# how to execute commands on putty from batch file?

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, putty

I want to open putty from my local machine and login automatically and then execute some commands on putty.

I tried the following steps:

created a batch file try.bat

```
start D:\putty.exe -ssh ip-l root -pw password

cd "/root/something"

ls -a

scp "somefile.." root@ip "somelocation"
```

The first step works fine. It opens the putty with the given username and password.

Other commands which are present on the batch file are not working.

Can anyone help me on how to execute these commands on putty from batch file?

Answer (score 1):

move the last 3 commands to a seperate file

say D:\scripts\commands.txt

then your batch file simply can contain

```
D:\putty.exe -ssh ip-l root -pw password -m "D:\scripts\commands.txt"
```

Reference:  Section 3.7.3.6  https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter3.html

Comment: try the updated answer. Did you create a new file at the location specified?

Comment: Yep, I have created the file. But I am getting a error message saying "unable to open the command file" in spite of giving the correct path to the command file. I tried to enclose the command file path in single quotes or double quotes or without quotes. Nothing works.

Comment: start will take the first argument with double quotes as the window title, insert a pair of double quotes just following start